# Поиск определенных результатов из миллиардов сочетаний

Tags: алгоритм, golang, математика, перебор

Задача найти оптимальные значения.

Есть 6 изменяемых параметров, по каждому есть размер шага и min/max. Общее число таких сочетаний больше 15 миллиардов, так что простой перебор считается очень и очень долго. Необходимо найти результаты, которые удовлетворяют заданным параметрам, рассчитанным на базе исходных (их 5) и при этом дающим максимальный результат. При этом надо отобрать не один результат, а топ 10-20.

Есть ли какие-то варианты, кроме тупо перебора вложенными циклами? Перебор сейчас очень медленный, необходимо значительно быстрее это делать.

Comment: Показывайте целевую функцию, которую надо максимизировать. Не зная вида целевой функции, не о чем говорить (кроме как о "тупо переборе")

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, вам нужен либо [генетический алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC) (у меня с подобными задачами приемлемо справляется [метод дифференциальной эволюции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)), либо [метод имитации отжига](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0) (последний по идее лучше, если неизвестно каких-либо дополнительных данных, но у меня не удалось его довести до ума).

Обратите внимание, эти методы не дают гарантированного оптимума, но зато позволяют с высокой вероятностью достаточно быстро получить результат, близкий к оптимуму (**по значению**, не по аргументу, если функция сильно "рваная", то по аргументу мы можем оказаться довольно далеко от оптимального аргумента, упав в локальный минимум, который по значению очень близок к настоящему оптимуму).

Если же вам нужен гарантированный оптимум, то только полный перебор (брутфорс). Ничего лучше не существует в принципе.